# genesis grid loop only showing one column

Tags: genesis-theme-framework

The following code is in `home.php` and works, mostly. It's not displaying a grid though. Instead it's displaying the featured image from the feature post at the top which is fine but the grid posts/images are all in a single column below the featured post. Is there something else I need to do?

```
<?php
remove_action('genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop');
add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'gabbro_posts_grid_loop' );
function gabbro_posts_grid_loop() {

  if ( function_exists( 'genesis_grid_loop' ) ) {
    genesis_grid_loop( array(
      'features' => 1,
      'feature_image_size' => 1,
      'feature_image_class' => 'align none post-image',
      'feature_content_limit' => 250,
      'grid_image_size' => 'grid-image',
      'grid_image_class' => 'align none post-image',
      'grid_content_limit' => 20,
      'more' => __( 'Continue reading...', 'genesis' ),
      'posts_per_page' => 5,
    ) );
  } else {

    genesis_standard_loop();

  }

}

genesis();
```

functions.php is:

```
add_image_size('grid-image', 250, 79, TRUE);
add_image_size('featured-image', 1102, 350, TRUE);
```

[gist for blog.html](https://gist.github.com/codebrane/595a18f0ee2e2e4da9f2d1d288c5543a)
[gist for style.css](https://gist.github.com/codebrane/ce2a862ec3c712c682508d34b797255f)

Comment: That sounds like a problem with styles. It would help if you have a link to the page where this appears, or could share the output + CSS.

Comment: sorry but it's running on a raspberry pi locally. It's the gensis sample theme without any modifications to style.css .site-inner is very narrow though, max-width: 1140px; and the list of posts page is crammed into the middle of the page. As you say, perhaps not enough room for two columns but I can't see where to make it full width. The page itself is full width template but is only half the width when displayed.

Comment: Can you maybe copy the output (html + css) to a Gist/CodePen or similar (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/top-7-code-sharing-website-for-developers/)? If this is a style thing as I suspect the answer will be either in the wrapper class applied around the grid elements or in the classes on each grid item, but it's impossible to say without seeing the code.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I've added gists for blog.html and style.ss

Comment: I'm not seeing any grid styles applied to the div that wraps around the articles, so I'm not sure how the grid would ever work. (See https://codepen.io/friendlywp/pen/QWOdNXy) This may be a question you have to ask on the Genesis theme forums. You can also check out https://www.billerickson.net/genesis-grid-loop-content/

Comment: thanks for looking, very much appreciated